# How to find unique word number of occurrences?

Tags: c, arrays, string

Can't figure out the bug in my code. Every time I input a sentence, the count does increment but the word adds the first letter of the previous word and increments one letter every time. How do I fix this?

````
void numberOfWordOccurrences(char str[MAX_CHAR]) {
int count = 0, i = 0, j = 0;
  char uniqueToken[99][999];
  int tokenCount[99] = {0}; 
  while(str[i] != '\0') {
    char token[999];  
    while(str[i] != ' ' && str[i] != '\0') {
      token[j++] = str[i++];
    }
    if(token[j - 1] == ':' || token[j - 1] == ',' || token[j - 1] == '.' || token[j - 1] == ';' || token[j - 1] == '?' || token[j - 1] == '!') {
      token[j - 1] = '\0';
    }
    //null 
    token[j] = '\0';
    //flag 
    int flag = -1; 
    for(j = 0; j < count; j++) {
      if(strcmp(uniqueToken[j], token) == 0) {
        //if flag is valid, then...
        flag = j;
        tokenCount[flag] = token[flag] + 1;
        break;
      }
    }
    if(flag <= 1) {
      tokenCount[count] = tokenCount[count] + 1;
      strcpy(uniqueToken[count++], token);
    }
    i++;
  }
}```
````

Comment: it'll make it easier for others to help you if you can provide some sample input and output as well as errors.  
however, in order to store a new work in the token, you should set the j back to 0 at the beginning of the loop before adding characters to token. otherwise, since the token is not initialized, it could have some undetermined values. in this case, it could be the character you previously stored in the token.

Answer (score 0):

first you have to set `j=0` inside of your main while loop ,otherwise when you go inside of this loop `for(j = 0; j < count; j++)`  `j`will in increase , so here `token[j++] = str[i++];` you won't start to copy `str` in `token` from `j=0` that is why you have previous words letters.

second I believe this condition `if(flag <= 1)` should be `if(flag == -1)` because if for example first and fifth word are similar flag would be `0` and again that string would be copied in `uniqueToken`.

also pay attention if you reach `\0` you with your two `i++` you will pass it and here `while(str[i] != '\0')` you won't check it so I suggest `while(str[i-1] != '\0')` also before sending string check if there  is anything in it(in a case `str[0]='\0'`.

look

```
void numberOfWordOccurrences(char str[]) {
    int count = 0, i = 0, j = 0;
    char uniqueToken[99][999];
    int tokenCount[99] = { 0 };
    while (str[i-1] != '\0') {
        j = 0;
        char token[999];
        while (str[i] != ' ' && str[i] != '\0') {
            token[j++] = str[i++];
        }
        if (token[j - 1] == ':' || token[j - 1] == ',' || token[j - 1] == '.' || token[j - 1] == ';' || token[j - 1] == '?' || token[j - 1] == '!') {
            token[j - 1] = '\0';
        }
        //null 
        token[j] = '\0';
        //flag 
        int flag = -1;
        for (j = 0; j < count; j++) {
            if (strcmp(uniqueToken[j], token) == 0) {
                //if flag is valid, then...
                flag = j;
                tokenCount[flag] = token[flag] + 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (flag == -1) {
            tokenCount[count] = tokenCount[count] + 1;
            strcpy(uniqueToken[count++], token);
            strcpy(uniqueToken[count], "\0");
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```